# Loop through first 5 items, then create ul and list the rest

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

Im trying to create some sort of sorting function on a bloglist. I want to output the first 5 items, and then create a more button, and list the rest of the categories to sort from.

I've got this so far:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
var blogitems = Umbraco.Content("1102").Children.Where("Visible");
<ul>
@foreach(var blog in blogitems) {
    var tagsplit = blog.blogCats.Split(',');
    var usedTags=new List<string>();
    foreach(var tag in tagsplit) {

        //Output the first 5 items, then create a new <ul> and then list the rest

        if(!usedTags.Contains(tag)){
            <li>                    
                    <a href="/blog/?@tag">@tag</a>
            </li>
        }
        usedTags.Add(tag);
    }
}
</ul>
 }
```

I hope it makes sense?

The wanted output in the end should look something like :

```
<ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="sort-item">Cat1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="sort-item">Cat2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="sort-item">Cat3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="sort-item">Cat4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="sort-item">Cat5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="sort-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-1-col.html">Cat6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-2-col.html">Cat7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-3-col.html">Cat8</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: `Take(5)` and `Skip(5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using System.Linq
@using System.Xml.Linq
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var blogitems = Umbraco.Content("1102").Children.Where("Visible");
    <ul>
        @foreach (var blog in blogitems)
        {
            var tagsplit = blog.blogCats.Split(',');
            var usedTags = new List<string>();

            var i = 1;
            foreach (var tag in tagsplit)
            {

                //Output the first 5 items, then create a new <ul> and then list the rest
                if (i <= 5)
                {

                    if (!usedTags.Contains(tag))
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="/blog/?@tag">@tag</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                    usedTags.Add(tag);

                }

                i += 1;
            }

            <li><a href="#" class="sort-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More <b class="caret"></b></a></li>
            <ul>

                @{
                    i = 1;
                    foreach (var tag in tagsplit)
                    {
                        if (i > 5)
                        {

                            if (!usedTags.Contains(tag))
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/blog/?@tag">@tag</a>
                                </li>
                            }
                            usedTags.Add(tag);


                        }

                        i += 1;
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        }
    </ul>
```

Comment: Nope, i always returns 5 then - So it will never output the "more" button, and the second ul

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look something like this:

```
@using System.Linq
@using System.Data.Linq
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
var blogitems = Umbraco.Content("1102").Children.Where("Visible");
<ul>
@foreach(var blog in blogitems) {
    var tagsplit = blog.blogCats.Split(',').ToList();
    var usedTags=new List<string>();
    foreach(var tag in tagsplit.Take(5)) {

        //Output the first 5 items, then create a new <ul> and then list the rest

        if(!usedTags.Contains(tag)){
            <li>                    
                    <a href="/blog/?@tag">@tag</a>
            </li>
        }
        usedTags.Add(tag);
    }


    <a href="#" class="sort-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    foreach(var tag in tagsplit.Skip(5)) {

       if(!usedTags.Contains(tag)){
            <li>                    
                    <a href="/blog/?@tag">@tag</a>
            </li>
       }
       usedTags.Add(tag);

    }
    </ul>
}
</ul>
```

}

Comment: Im getting this error: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Take' ? It like you cant use Take on the foreach ?

Comment: Please add `@using System.Data.Linq` at the top of your Razor page. Should work! I have also updated my answer, so you can see the using directive at the top of the page.

Comment: Or System.Linq, possibly.

Comment: Still getting the same error after adding @using System.Linq :/

Comment: Ahhh, it bacause when using Split(","); - Then it is an array, the array does not have the method Take() avaiable?

Comment: Yes, correct. Please add `.ToList()` to the tagsplit assignment, like this: `var tagsplit = blog.blogCats.Split(',').ToList();`. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, still getting the same error when doing that? :(

Comment: Well, almost same error, this is the error now: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

Comment: I believe you have to use System.Linq and System.Data.Linq namespaces. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I am using System.Linq - But im getting the same error as before: System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' on the line: var tagsplit = blog.blogCats.Split(',').ToList();

Comment: You also have a reference to `System.Core`? The easiest way is to include these namespaces - `System.Core`, `System.Linq`,`System.Data.Linq`, `System.Xml.Linq` into the web.config file of your project, here: `'<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Core"/>'` etc

Comment: Cant get it to work... However, tried something else, see down below - Any takes on that solution=

Comment: Yes, you put `var i = 0;` before the `foreach` loop. It will work.